# sharing big float arrays between C/C++ and javascript applications

Tags: javascript, c++, typescript, network-protocols

I have  float arrays, that are positions of  3D objects computed by a C++ program. the chunk size will be 1000. 
I have to share these data with a javascript visualisation program that will display the 3d mobiles positions depending on the time.
How to share these arrays between the C++ (server side) and javascript (client side) application through the network ? which protocol can I use ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Node.Js Buffers for this? nodejs allows you to move data fairly seamlessly between javascript and native C++ code. Explained a bit better here ->[Node.Js Buffers](https://community.risingstack.com/using-buffers-node-js-c-plus-plus/)

Comment: Yes, I did consider it. But that lacks of an overview of what is done server side and client side.It's confusing to understand how it will operate in my case. The node buffer c++ api remains in server side and must be executed on server side. I understand that will permit to share this C buffer with javascript.  Do you consider server side rendering mandatory ? in any case, there is an amount of data that must be transfered client side ?

Comment: The solution seems being using a websocket stream to receive data from C++ program server side and storing in a NodeJS buffer client side.